# Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras and software center issue

Tags: installation, software-center

I use Lenovo G450 and just installed 11.10, but hadn't checked third party software installation at that time. Now, when i code **"sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras,"** i am getting this message **"Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras".**

Also, when I try from Software center, there is **"updating cache"** running from long time and this selection for **restricted-extras** adds two more **"updating cache"** and **"enabling component of the distribution"**. All in waiting mode.
what should I do??

Answer (score 1):

You need to kill all instances of the update manager. To do this you can Ctrl+Alt+t to open a terminal and type `sudo killall update-manager`

Now you need to manager the update-manager.

Alt+F2 type `update-manager` once it opens go to settings and uncheck automatic updates. This will allow you to manually manage the apt process. --you will no longer receive automatic updates. You should be able to add restricted extras without interruption.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```